# Multivariate discrete distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, discrete-data

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_{1}, \dots, x_{m})$ be a vector of discrete variable; $x_{j} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Which distribution can I use over $\mathbf{x}$ that allows to have dependence between each couple $(x_j, x_i)$, $i,j=1,\dots,m$? Morover,  let $\rho_{ij}$ be the covariance between $(x_j, x_i)$, I also need  that  $\rho_{ij}$ can be different from $\rho_{rt}$

I need it for a Bayesian model where $m$ is between 2 and 20.